# Unable to detect adb version, adb output in Android Studio 3.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

I have done following task for solutions;

- Download and update platform-tools
- Change Sdk path and re-download
- Uninstalled Android Sdk platform-tools and Android Sdk tools after re-install.
- Update adb path in Environment
- Change virtual memory size

But it's still not working... I'm using android studio version 3.3.2

error show like Unable to detect adb version means connection devices showing none when i run the app

[image]

Comment: @pskink i updated my qns.. check it

Comment: @pskink - adb is not recognized and when i open cmd from platform-tools then it's show me the application was unable to start correctly

Comment: i installed it @pskink

Comment: try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Comment: i do it.. but not work show same error

Comment: it's show me application was unable to start correctly

Comment: @pskink when i enter those two command from cmd iit's show me error like application was unable to start correctly

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: @manindersingh yes i have done it.. that was visual studio c++ 2015 issue..just repair or re-installed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. That was the visual studio installation problem. In my system visual studio c++ 2015 installed. Just repair or re-installed it.

Answer (score 3):

If other solutions don't work and you're on Windows, check if Visual C ++ is installed.

If needed, you can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=48145&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True).

Answer (score 2):

Just change `adb.exe` in location  `sdk\platform-tools   -adb.exe` and replace it. It will work. SDK folder is in `users\account name\appdata\local\android\SDK\platform-tools`

In my case: `D:\ANDROID SETUP\sdk\platform-tools` due to low c drive space ..

It will work ......

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing issues with Android Studio 3.3.2 not detecting Genymotion: make sure to point Genymotion to use the Android SDK ADB and not the one it's shipped with. It seems like this is because Genymotion is shipped with outdated ADB

Answer (score 0):

Locate the adb.exe file in the platform-tools folder . Double-click to run it . If it shows an error message , you need to install the C++ runtime from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=48145&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True). Else you should up-date/reinstall the sdk

Answer (score 0):

i downgrade my adb  and use this as guidance 
https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/