# adb not working, not displaying any response

Tags: android, windows, command-line, adb, uiautomatorviewer

when trying to run `adb devices` no output is shown at all not even a empty list. The terminal waits as if it is going to load, but then it just creates a new  line prompt as if I hadn't given the `adb` command.

No `no devices found` is displayed or any indication that the bridge is running, literally nothing is displayed.

When trying to open the `uiautomatorview` I receive this error `E/adb: Unable to detect adb version, adb output:`

Solutions I have already tried:

- checking system variables
- changing the directory to run out of platform-tools directly
- checked port 5037 for other processes
- replacing the adb.exe
- uninstalled and re installed android studios
- replacing  just the SDK tools and platform tools
- uninstalled and reinstalled java

Please can someone help?

Comment: Try to kill the adb server and then start it again.

Comment: Probably a solution for your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217479/unable-to-detect-adb-version-adb-output-in-android-studio-3-3-2

Comment: @amrs-tech that doesn't work. I've tried killing it and restarting multiple times.

Comment: @MIld_error Sorry, maybe try SandyRagaie suggesting SO answer

Comment: @SandyRagaie I have tried all solutions on that question, unfortunately still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem at least a few times already, every time I just turned off and on my mac again and it started to work again. I don't know why it happens though.

And I know it's not the perfect solution, but it worked, so I just thought I'm gonna share it with the others.

By the way restarting the mac didn't solve the problem, only turning it off and on again.