# How to solve error "Unable to detect adb version"?

Tags: android

While I install Android studion, I succeed in sync but then it throws error when running and shows **"unable to detect adb version"**. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55217479/unable-to-detect-adb-version-adb-output-in-android-studio-3-3-2 Please see the link

Comment: please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask